# View Transition stammering when KeyBoard comes up iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, ios7, uiviewanimationtransition

Here is a transition code I have for Showing ViewB from ViewA

```
CGPoint c = thepoint;
CGFloat tx = c.x - floorf(theview.center.x) + 10;
CGFloat ty = c.y - floorf(theview.center.y) + 100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Transforms
                     CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tx, ty);
                     t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 0.1, 0.1);
                     theview.transform = t;
                     theview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                     [theview setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                 }];
```

Now that the transition went very smooth without issues.

When in my ViewB, I had a text box with default focus. (In `viewDidAppear`)

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:NO];
    [self performSelector:@selector(focusCommentText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void) focusCommentText {
[self focusTextbox:commentText];
}

- (void) focusTextbox : (UITextView *) textView{
    @try {
        [ textView becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

    }
}
```

The Transition and the Keyboard coming up.. happens at same time.. And it is slightly awkward now. Can some one help me out here please?

Comment: It just means those two animations cannot run simultaneously with good performance on current generation hardware. You'll need to find a way to not do those two animations at the same time.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert you were right!!! I fixed my code as you said.. And I had posted it as a new answer as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: if that's what you ended up doing you should mark that as your accepted answer, instead of matt's one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** The killer was actually the background color of my view was transparent with alpha 0.8. Once I made it opaque (alpha = 1.0), the animation was smooth!!

---

I modified my code to make the focus of text box only after completion of the animation.

```
CGPoint c = thepoint;
CGFloat tx = c.x - floorf(theview.center.x) + 10;
CGFloat ty = c.y - floorf(theview.center.y) + 100;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Transforms
                     CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(tx, ty);
                     t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 0.1, 0.1);
                     theview.transform = t;
                     theview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
                     [theview setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if( theview.tag == 1000) {
                         if(myVC != nil)
                             [myVC focusCommentText]; /// Here is where I set focus
                     }
                 }];
```

When `CATransition` is used, it is the delegate `animationDidStop` I have to choose.

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.4;
    transition.type = kCATransitionFromRight; //choose your animation
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFade;
    transition.delegate = self; //Setting Delegate as Self

    [self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:myVC.view];


#pragma mark - CATransition Delegate
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
{
    if(myVC != nil) {
        [myVC focusCommentText];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is *not* call `[textView becomeFirstResponder]` until *after* the transition has *completed*.

Comment: Thanks! I modified my code to make the focus on `completion` of **Animation** and for **CATransition** I implemented the same in delegate `animationDidStop`